# calling another bat in a bat file with the resulting message in another file .txt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I created a .bat which calls another .bat at a certain point. I've added @echo=off at the beginning of my script and this is the command I use:

```
    call %DSRuntime%\dstools deleteCollection -i %%a > fisier.txt
```

The problem is that if the command can be executed correctly the file fisier.txt is created an filled with the information I need, but if there is a problem the message is displayed on the screen, not in my file.
Also, if I pass the command in cmd I get errorlevel=1, in my script, I get 0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the error message is written to stderr. Have you tried `call %DSRuntime%\dstools deleteCollection -i %%a > fisier.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Yes, I did after I posted the question and now it's solved! Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).